# Cookie XSRF-TOKEN created without the secure flag - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cookies, laravel-5.8

I am using Laravel **5.8** .

I use **Nikto** to scan my site, I saw these issues.

- Cookie XSRF-TOKEN created without the secure flag
- Cookie XSRF-TOKEN created without the httponly flag
- Cookie laravel_session created without the secure flag

How do I patch these issues in my Laravel Site ?

I've tried , but it clearly not wotking. :(

```
header('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block');
header('Content-Security-Policy', 'default-src \'self\'');
header('X-Frame-Options','deny');
header("X-Frame-Options: DENY");
header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'", false);
```

Any suggestions on a properway of patching these issues ?

---

## session.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
    | cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
    | correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
    |
    */

    'store' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => env('SESSION_HTTP_ONLY', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | do not enable this as other CSRF protection services are in place.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict"
    |
    */

    'same_site' => env('SESSION_SAME_SITE', null),

];
```

---

**.env**

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
SESSION_HTTP_ONLY=true
SESSION_SAME_SITE=strict
```

---

## Update

*After update session.php base on `@ceejayoz` answer.*

Right now, I only see this issues

> - Cookie XSRF-TOKEN created without the httponly flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the values for `secure` and `http_only` in [`config/session.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php).

Comment: You mean like this `'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),` ??

Comment: These `'http_only' => true,` should be false ? for secure ?

Comment: Can you please advise and include the correct settings in your answer ?

Comment: Both should be set to true to turn those flags on.

Comment: Okay sure. How about the domain should I put something ? Like my site domain ?

Comment: I don't mess with that, typically. Most of the defaults are just fine.